# Come to our Berlin launch party of Careers 2.0 in German!

Tags: discussion, meetups

[As you may have read](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/11/join-stack-overflow-in-berlin-for-a-blowout-bash-on-december-5/), we're partying in Germany next month (because no one parties like the Germans) to announce the launch of our first translation of Careers 2.0 in German. We hope you can join us on December 5 in Berlin! [Here are the detail](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/launch)s.

In the meantime, feel free to continue to give us [feedback on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156432/feedback-wanted-careers-in-german). Post your questions, stories, or travel plans below.

Hope to see you all there!

Comment: No one parties like the Germans? You haven't been to Greece, have you? Our parties are legendary, and the best thing is: Germans are paying for them ;)

Comment: Too scared Pekka will show up with a flame thrower.

Comment: Too scared Pekka will show up, period.

Comment: Guys when you will  translate it in Hindi? :P

Comment: Ohh man! It will probably be impossible for me to come due to pressing commitments on that day and the next in, literally, the other end of the country... I'll try to do something about it but I'm not optimistic. :( @Oded, Pop I'm expecting SE, Inc. will be providing some state of the art flamethrowers on site! There will be a BBQ of some really bad questions. *Flambé.*

Comment: Obviously you don't work out of the New York office.

Comment: @casper why, do they have Flamethrowers?

Comment: @Pekka Yes, we spit fire. [Case in point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3wIJ774gJs)

Comment: Waaait a minute, @Pekka... You were in the US during the Denver meetup but on the wrong side of the country, now you're gonna be in Germany during the Berlin meetup but *again* on the wrong side of the country! Please tell me when you plan to travel to the UK, so we can plan a London party while you're in Glasgow...

Comment: @Pekka Come on, Germany can't be *that* big, can it? ;)

Comment: @AnnaLear It's not as vast as the frozen tundras of Canada, that's for sure.

Comment: @Shog When Careers finally launches in Trinidad, I will happen to be in Tobago. It's Karma!

Comment: I definitely won't make it :( Have fun guys, and post photos!