# Edit buttons of profile page drawn over profile picture

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs, design, careers-germany

The Buttons "Bearbeiten" to edit my profile and tags are drawn over my profile picture. See screen-shot below.

> [image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156432/feedback-wanted-careers-in-german/156455#156455

Comment: @balpha thanks for the link. I´m not sure. Should bugs of Careers germany posted in the linked question or is it ok to open a new question?

Comment: That's okay at this point. Often time at the launch of a particular feature we like to have all feedback and issues in a single place like that question, but we're beyond that point now; new question is fine.

Comment: This has slipped through the cracks due to missing [tag:careers] tag, hence the Careers team never saw this. Fixed now. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 4):

We are working on a new UI for the Profile edition page, it should be shipped soon™, and it fixes this bug.

A little more patience :)

Thanks for the report!